# How does Excel determine the min / max of the Y Axis?

Tags: microsoft-excel, axis

As the title asks, how does Excel set the min max for the Y axis.

I have a line chart with a series plotted across 36 points, the values range from 457 - 514.

Whilst the Y-axis min/max are set to auto I get a min/ max of 420/520.

What calculation does Excel use for this ?

Comment: Check [this](https://peltiertech.com/how-excel-calculates-automatic-chart-axis-limits/) out.

Comment: @PeterH, did you try Format Axis ,, Bound `Max` & `Min` option? Set `Max 514.0`,  `Min 457.0` & for `Units Major 3.0`, `Minor 1.0`. U get scale from `457-514`. I've reproduced it successfully.

Comment: Hi @RajeshS I only wanted to know how Excel sets min/max

Comment: Means the mechanism behind it !! Excel takes the lowest value as Minimum & highest as Maximum from Source data Range.